# Is it possible to retrieve the specific value in an array of objects inside an object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to retrieve the specific value in an array of objects inside an another object in mongodb??

```
@Document
class vehicleStation {
   @Id
   String stationId;
   List<car> cars;
}
@Document
class car{
   @Id
   String carNo;
   String name;
}
```

And my json structure will look like below

> {"_id":"0001","cars":[{"_id":"C001",
>   "name":"Honda"},{"_id":"C002","name":"Ford"}]}

Is it possible retrieve the value of "name" for a particular vehicleStation (stationId="0001" and carNo="C002") which is "Ford"

how to query the mongodb to get the value "Ford" for vehicleStation (stationId="0001" and carNo="C002")

Comment: I am able update the data and i dont know how to reterive the data without iterating through the list of object from the java side 'Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("stationId").is("0001").andOperator(Criteria.where("cars.carNo").is("C002")));mongoTemplate.upsert(query, new Update().set("cars.$.name", "BMW"), Car.class);`

Comment: Not familiar with spring but there should be some methods like `find` or `findOne` with ability to set return fields along with `where`-clause.

Comment: yes... It will return only the object but i want a specific value in the inner object.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using the [$elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator. e.g. from the shell

```
> db.so.find({_id:"0001"},{cars:{$elemMatch:{"_id":"C002"}}})
{ "_id" : "0001", "cars" : [  {  "_id" : "C002",  "name" : "Ford" } ] }
```

Comment: It is returning the document object. But i want either the value "Ford" alone or inner object that matches the query ({"_id":"C002","name":"Ford"})

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing an _id query at the top level this returns only one document. You can do

```
db.so.findOne({_id:"0001"},{cars:{$elemMatch:{"_id":"C002"}}}).cars[0]
```

to get the inner object or

```
db.so.findOne({_id:"0001"},{cars:{$elemMatch:{"_id":"C002"}}}).cars[0].name
```

to get only the name
Note - If you have multiple subobjects with the _id as C002 this will only the first match as [documented](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/).